# rospack error(libboost_system_mt-1.48.so)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm trying to cross-compile Nao V4.
But when I use rospack command, following error message comes out.

rospack: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_system-mt-1_48.so.1.48.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I tried installing library files by "$ sudo apt-get install libboost-system libboost-dev etc. But nothing has been solved.

In fact, I found out this error when I tried to source $TARGETDIR/workspace_nao/setup.bash, which contained "rospack" command. This content came from [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/nao/Tutorials/Cross-Compiling_NAO-V4#Creating_a_workspacehttp://). When I tried to source setup.bash, following error message came out.

rospack could not be found, you cannot have rosbash features until you bootstrap ros

So I think that it is the error coming from rospack error related with library(libboost?).

Is there Anyone who knows the solution?

Thanks in advance! :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66398/rospack-error(libboost_system_mt-1.48.so)/) by [Oppenheim](https://answers.ros.org/users/3432/oppenheim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2013-07-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Oppenheim](https://answers.ros.org/users/3432/oppenheim/) on 2013-07-02**:
Actually, I'm using ubuntu 10.04 now, but I'm not sure why libboost1.48 is needed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you have switched Ubuntu versions you need to make sure to clean all build artifacts.  Likely you have either a CMakeCache or simply libraries which were linked on the other OS and now cannot be loaded because there's a different version of boost installed.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0